# Visual Studio - AppBuilder - Git Hub - .sou file issue

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, telerik-appbuilder

I started a project on Telerik's AppBuilder and then started working on that project in Visual Studio 2015.  I was able to commit.  Note that I have a desktop and laptop, both with VS2015 and working on this project.  So, I was able to commit and sync on the Desktop and Laptop a few weeks ago.  Then, I made some changes on the desktop and tried to checkin, and now I get "unable to access .suo file for writing" when trying to sync and have been unable to checkin to Git since then on the Desktop, but on the Laptop I can push/pull w/o issue.

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What is in your `.gitignore` file? The `.suo` file is user-specific, and thus should generally not be committed to Git. Also please post the output of `git status` from the command line (probably Git Bash).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be checking in `.suo` files into Git, they contain user data that should not be shared.  Instead, you should be marking them to be "ignored" by Git, so that they will *never* be checked in and *never* detected as an untracked file.

However, Git will only ignore files that are *not* already in the repository.  So you must remove them before you can ignore them.

First, add the `.suo` file to your `.gitignore`.  Create a `.gitignore` file at the base of your Git repository, and add the following line to it:

```
*.suo
```

*Or*, better yet, download the [`VisualStudio.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file and name it `.gitignore`, placing it at the root of your repository.  This file is an excellent set of `.gitignore` rules for Visual Studio projects.  (And if you had created your project in Visual Studio it would have prompted you to set this up - but don't worry, it's not too late!)

Next, remove the `.suo` file from your repository.  If the `.suo` file in question is `MySolution.suo`:

```
git rm --cached MySolution.suo
git commit -m"Remove .suo file" MySolution.suo
```

Now when Visual Studio changes your `.suo` file, you will not be prompted to add it or check it in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have a few questions.

Comment: There was already a .gitignore at the root of the solution.  So I added in a new line: *.suo

Now do I remove the .suo from the repository.  I have downloaded the Git CLI and I have navigated to the project's root.  When I execute the git rm ... command I get an error: "fatal: pathspec 'MySolution.suo' did not match any files.  

Should I be inside the .git folder? or on the root of the project where the .gitignore file is?

Comment: @RobertGreen Just to be clear, replace `MySolution.suo` with the path to your `.suo` file.  Or you can run `git rm --cached '*.suo'` to remove them all from the repository.  (Correct, run this command from the root of your project, not from inside the `.git` folder.)

Comment: @@EdwardThomson thanks for your assistance, maybe you can answer the next thing that happened after you helped me solve for the above...