# Git Push/Pull VS 2015 Issue

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-push, git-pull

So, I'm just getting [this issue resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111213/visual-studio-appbuilder-git-hub-sou-file-issue) with my .suo file, and now I get this screen.  I can't push or pull.  I get this error when trying to push from my Desktop, however my Laptop is able to push.  Now, another, and most important note, is that the code (the actual files - *project files*) actually exist in the cloud as this is a Telerik AppBuilder application which I am using VS2015 as my IDE.

Now, to recap the problem: My Laptop can Push/Pull, my desktop cannot (see my comments and image below); however I do have a "latest" version of the code (in the cloud) as a good base.

Please keep in mind considerations:

I am using TFS and would like to link my TFS Tasks with check-ins (for later reference). (See pending checkins?  I have them associated with TFS tasks, so I would prefer not to loose them and rebase...)

What is my best way forward?

[image: My current experience]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696295/rejected-master-master-non-fast-forward)

Comment: Your best way forward is to read about basic git workflows and understand them without opening Visual Studio at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Moved from a comment.**

You can't push when you are behind the branch head. That is written out in plain english in the alert.

You can't pull (fetch+merge) when you have uncommitted changes to one of the affected files.

**So, you probably need to:** Stage your files, commit, pull, fix conflicts + stage/commit them, then push.

Hope that helps. I don't use VS, so I can't tell if you have any unstaged/uncommitted changes. That is my guess.

Comment: I have just updated my question.  Does this change your answer?

Comment: Can you commit (without pushing) your local files? Try that first, and get back to me.

Comment: How can I commit w/o pushing local files?  On my desktop (which is the screen above) I have already committed but cannot push to Git.

Comment: If you've already committed, you need to now pull. Please read my answer again in detail. Commit, pull, push.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like someone else has committed changes to the branch and you haven't pulled them into your local branch.  You need to do that and resolve any conflicts that may show up.  Once that is done you can push your changes to the branch

Comment: When I try to pull it says: Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before pulling again.

Comment: I have just updated my question.  Does this change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you have uncommitted changes you need to commit them. afterwards, you should pull changes from origin master and solve conflicts if needed, and then you could push your changes to remote.

Comment: I have just updated my question.  Does this change your answer?

Comment: If the error message hasn't changed, then unfortunately no,it doesn't change it.  There are still changes you haven't pulled in, and you have to do that before you can push your changes up.  Those changes you need to pull in would overwrite some of your local changes, that's why you are getting the message